# Is a portable version of MySQL for Linux available?

Tags: mysql, linux, portability

Is a portable version of MySQL for Linux available?

Comment: What is your definition of portable?

Comment: hi Andrew.. its like run-it-anywhere on any linux machine without installation and much configurations... like there is a no-installer-zip for Windows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to "install" mysql. Its binaries will run from any directory (given appropriate search paths etc), and its configuration can be specified entirely on the command-line, if necessary, bypassing the likes of /etc/my.cnf, or by specifying an alternative config file with arbitrary path.

Some engines can work with a readonly data directory (MyISAM, Archive), others may require a read/write data directory (Innodb) but that could be a temporary area or ramdisc.

There's nothing "un-portable" about MySQL.

Comment: Even though Rajan accepted, I think it is not the solution. "portable", as in "PortableApps", means you can move the app's directory anywhere, and then just run its executable. No configuration to do after moving it, which means all paths are relative.

Comment: that part is native in linux, using chroot

Comment: Download link https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/, just download the dpkg, and extract

Answer (score 4):

To have a Portable Version of MySQL in linux, you can compile it to a Generic location

```
./configure --prefix=/myworkspace/installs/mysql --exec-prefix=/myworkspace/installs/mysql
```

Then usual

```
make
make install
```

this will install mysql on /myworkspace/installs/mysql. Then you can zip the whole mysql folder and can take it anywhere except you can run it from the same directory structure you have installed. Compiling mysql requires some dependencies, check it out here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/source-installation.html .
If you install these dependencies also in /myworkspace/installs/mysqldepends/ , then your mysql is totally portable.

Answer (score 1):

[MySQL Embedded Server](http://www.mysql.com/oem/) is available for purchase.

Comment: I believe Firebird has something similar, but that's not quite MySQL. It is closer than SQLite though.

Answer (score -2):

I advice you to use SQLite